# Compiling hevea-2.19 with Objective Caml compiler v3.11.2

Tags: hevea

Hevea is a LaTeX to HTML converter, available from http://pauillac.inria.fr/~maranget/hevea/index.html

I am trying (and failing) to compile hevea on a CentOS machine for which the yum repositories do not seem to have a package. I have installed the packaged Objective Caml compiler as follows:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ppserver 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 9 21:36:05
UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ sudo yum install ocaml
...
$ /usr/bin/ocamlc.opt -v
The Objective Caml compiler, version 3.11.2
Standard library directory: /usr/lib64/ocaml
```

Attempting to compile hevea gives:

```
$ wget http://pauillac.inria.fr/~maranget/hevea/distri/hevea-2.19.tar.gz
$ tar -zxvf hevea-2.19.tar.gz
$ cd hevea-2.19
[hevea-2.19]$ make
sh ocb.sh opt
/usr/bin/ocamldep.opt -modules hevea.ml > hevea.ml.depends
/usr/bin/ocamldep.opt -modules auxx.mli > auxx.mli.depends
...
/usr/bin/ocamlc.opt -c -w +a-4-9-41-45 -annot -o videoc.cmi videoc.mli
/usr/bin/ocamlc.opt -c -w +a-4-9-41-45 -annot -o zyva.cmi zyva.mli
+ /usr/bin/ocamlc.opt -c -w +a-4-9-41-45 -annot -o infoRef.cmo infoRef.ml
File "infoRef.mll", line 127, characters 2-12:
Error: Unbound value String.map
Command exited with code 2.
make: *** [ocb-opt] Error 10
```

This is the code triggering the error,

```
let verifie name =
  String.map
    (fun c -> match c  with
    | '\t'
    | ','
    | '\n' -> ' '
    | '.' -> '-'
    |  _ -> c)
    name
;;
```

My guess is something has changed in the Objective Caml compiler and the hevea code needs some slight update? I have emailed Luc Maranget and will post any reply here [see below].

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! I think this is probably off-topic for this site, and almost certainly not the best place to ask it. Mostly questions here are about using the software rather than compiling it - I suspect you'd get better help on one of the sites dedicated to Unix/Linux or whatever. I'm not going to vote to close right now, though, because I'm far from sure about the site policy on this.

Comment: The current version of OCaml is 4.02.1. Is there a particular reason why you are using 3.11.2?

Comment: It was the OCaml compiler available via the yum repositories on this machine, and thus the easiest one to install. This turned out to be too old (much older than I had guessed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an email reply from Luc Maranget,

> You simply need an ocaml compiler more recent than 3.11.2,
>   ideally the current version ...
>   String.map was introduced un OCaml 4.00.0
>
> In any case I sugest that you upgrade your installation of OCaml
>   to the current version. The ocaml provided by your linux
>   distribution is obsolete, as OCaml 3.11.2 was released in
>   January 2010. A convenient mean to install OCaml is by the
>   means of opam http://opam.ocamlpro.com/

Hopefully this Q&A will help someone else in future.